# Random name generator in c#

Tags: c#, random, names

I have a list of female and male first names then a list of last names in arrays.

What I was trying to do was use the random generator to take those names in those arrays and output a random first name and last name depending on what I call.

After I finish that I was going to reference that method in other classes instead of having to write it out each individual time.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
  private void RandName()
  {
        string[] maleNames = new string[1000] { "aaron", "abdul", "abe", "abel", "abraham", "adam", "adan", "adolfo", "adolph", "adrian"};
        string[] femaleNames = new string[1000] { "abby", "abigail", "adele", "adrian"};
        string[] lastNames = new string[1000] { "abbott", "acosta", "adams", "adkins", "aguilar"};

        Random rand = new Random(DateTime.Now.Second);
        if (rand.Next(1, 2) == 1)
        {
            FirstName = maleNames[rand.Next(0, maleNames.Length - 1)];
        }
        else
        {
            FirstName = femaleNames[rand.Next(0, femaleNames.Length - 1)];
        }

  }
```

**My Question is:** How to create a random name generator using the arrays of names I created?

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: Sorry about that, how to create a random name generator using the arrays of names I created.

Comment: @Dev24Amaya Please explain why the output you are getting does not match the output you are expecting. I've taken a guess below, but it is only a guess!

Comment: That's not going to be too random if you call the method twice over a second

Comment: You may want to declare your `rand` as a private static variable; if the user clicks to make a random name faster than 1 second, it will generate the same name. Also, just do it without manually specifying a seed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess the result of your random generator is the same every time..

If this is your problem, you shouldn't create local variable `rand` every time. Create field instead.

Smth like:

```
private static Random rand = new Random(DateTime.Now.Second);

private void RandName()
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: I would be carful of a static `Random`, the class is not Thread Safe, It would be better to not make it static (Also I would not seed it with `DateTime.Now.Second` and just use the default constructor which uses `Environment.TickCount` internally)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain could you explain how the random class works regarding seeds? My limited knowledge on the subject says the constructor takes an arbitrary number and uses that, which means `new Random(DateTime.Now.Second)` should not return the same number every time, though that seems not to be the case. How is the seed used?

Answer (score 24):

```
    public static string GenerateName(int len)
    { 
        Random r = new Random();
        string[] consonants = { "b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "l", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "sh", "zh", "t", "v", "w", "x" };
        string[] vowels = { "a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "ae", "y" };
        string Name = "";
        Name += consonants[r.Next(consonants.Length)].ToUpper();
        Name += vowels[r.Next(vowels.Length)];
        int b = 2; //b tells how many times a new letter has been added. It's 2 right now because the first two letters are already in the name.
        while (b < len)
        {
            Name += consonants[r.Next(consonants.Length)];
            b++;
            Name += vowels[r.Next(vowels.Length)];
            b++;
        }

        return Name;


     }
```

Comment: error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.Random' does not contain a definition for `Next' and no extension method `Next' of type `UnityEngine.Random' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: @WaqarKhan is referring to `System.Random` @SumitPal

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question of *"How to create a random name generator **using the arrays of names I created**?"*, but instead, creates a random string of alternating consonants and vowels.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, without knowing the problem you are facing, this is a bit of a stab in the dark, but I think your problem is that you've declared the array size as `1000`, but only entered around 10 values in each one. Therefore, your array is only 1% full, so you will mostly obtain empty names.

Try the following:

```
// Note I have not specified the array size.
string[] maleNames   = {"aaron", "abdul", "abe", "abel", "abraham", "adam", "adan", "adolfo", "adolph", "adrian"};
string[] femaleNames = {"abby", "abigail", "adele", "adrian"};
string[] lastNames   = {"abbott", "acosta", "adams", "adkins", "aguilar"};
```

Comment: It's worth noting what RB's actually done here - by removing the constaint of 1000 for the string array, the size of the array is determined by the number of elements provided in the {} and the array then dynamically defined.

Comment: @RB, I didn't put all 1000 values because that would be too much to include in the post but in the code there is that amount.

Comment: @Dev24Amaya As I said - it was a guess, because you haven't explained what problem you are facing!

Comment: Sorry about that! I am having a problem getting the random name from the array of names I created. I am making some adjustments now based on the answers below.

Answer (score 3):

Since the random instance is created in `RandName` you will create the same names when the method is called very fast(f.e. in a loop). You should use a field or pass the random as argument to the method.

Apart from that, you will never get to the `else` block here

```
if (rand.Next(1, 2) == 1)
```

since the second parameter of [`Random.Next`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx) is the exclusive upper bound and it always generates 1. So you might want this instead:

```
if (rand.Next(0, 2) == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Format you strings like so...

```
    string[] maleNames = new string[] { "aaron", "abdul", "abe", "abel", "abraham", "adam", "adan", "adolfo", "adolph", "adrian"};
    string[] femaleNames = new string[] { "abby", "abigail", "adele", "adrian"};
    string[] lastNames = new string[] { "abbott", "acosta", "adams", "adkins", "aguilar"};
```

Or For me the easier way is to use a List. I use them for iterating through files. The main differences are you have to add them one at a time using List.Add() and it uses List.Count instead of Array.Length. List also allow you to modify entries without having to resize the array. In your case the list you're trying to create would look like this

```
List<string> maleNames = new List<string>();
List<string> femaleNames = new List<string>();
List<string> lastNames = new List<string>();
```

then use System.IO to open separate files and read each line in to the three list. It's just the way that I'd do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public string GenerateToken(Byte length) {
        var bytes = new byte[length];
        var rnd = new Random();
        rnd.NextBytes(bytes);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes).Replace("=", "").Replace("+", "").Replace("/", "");
    }
```

Is a very simple generator ..

Answer (score 0):

While my first answer back in 2013 was a link only answer to an already outdated project, I'm using within our tests the following code:

```
namespace MockHelpers
{
    public static class NameGenerator
    {
        private static readonly Random _Random = new Random();
        private static readonly Lazy<string[]> _MaleNames = new Lazy<string[]>(() => Resources.MaleNames.Split((char[])null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
        private static readonly Lazy<string[]> _FemaleNames = new Lazy<string[]>(() => Resources.FemaleNames.Split((char[])null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
        private static readonly Lazy<string[]> _FamilyNames = new Lazy<string[]>(() => Resources.FamilyNames.Split((char[])null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

        public static IEnumerable<string> GetMaleNames()
        {
            return _MaleNames.Value.CreateEndlessRandomSequence(_Random);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<string> GetFemaleNames()
        {
            return _FemaleNames.Value.CreateEndlessRandomSequence(_Random);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<string> GetFamilyNames()
        {
            return _FamilyNames.Value.CreateEndlessRandomSequence(_Random);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<(string firstName, string lastName, Gender gender)> GetNames()
        {
            return new[] {
                GetMaleNames().Select(Name => (Name, Gender.Male)),
                GetFemaleNames().Select(Name => (Name, Gender.Female))
            }
                .Interweave()
                .Zip(GetFamilyNames(), (person, lastName) => (person.Name, lastName, person.Item2));
        }
    }

    public enum Gender
    {
        Unknown,
        Female,
        Male,
    }

    public static class EnumerableExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> CreateEndlessRandomSequence<T>(this IReadOnlyList<T> source, Random rng)
        {
            if (source == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
            }

            if (rng == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(rng));
            }

            return CreateEndlessRandomSequenceIterator(source, rng);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<T> Interweave<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sources)
        {
            if (sources == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sources));
            }

            var enumerators = sources.Select(source => source.GetEnumerator()).ToList();

            return InterweaveIterator(enumerators);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Random rng)
        {
            if (source == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
            }

            if (rng == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(rng));
            }

            var elements = source.ToArray();
            return ShuffleIterator(elements, rng);
        }

        private static IEnumerable<T> CreateEndlessRandomSequenceIterator<T>(IReadOnlyList<T> source, Random rng)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var shuffled = source.Shuffle(rng);

                foreach (var item in shuffled)
                {
                    yield return item;
                }
            }
        }

        private static IEnumerable<T> InterweaveIterator<T>(List<IEnumerator<T>> enumerators)
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    enumerators.RemoveAll(e =>
                    {
                        if (e.MoveNext())
                            return false;

                        e.Dispose();
                        return true;
                    });

                    if (enumerators.Count == 0)
                        yield break;

                    foreach (var e in enumerators)
                        yield return e.Current;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (enumerators != null)
                    foreach (var e in enumerators)
                        e.Dispose();
            }
        }

        private static IEnumerable<T> ShuffleIterator<T>(T[] elements, Random rng)
        {
            for (int i = elements.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                // Swap element "i" with a random earlier element it (or itself)
                // ... except we don't really need to swap it fully, as we can
                // return it immediately, and afterwards it's irrelevant.
                int swapIndex = rng.Next(i + 1);
                yield return elements[swapIndex];
                elements[swapIndex] = elements[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To use this you could simply call:

```
foreach (var item in NameGenerator.GetNames().Take(1000))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.gender} {item.firstName} {item.lastName}");
}
```

Also to make this code fully working you have to create the resource files, containing the desired list of sur and given names. These have to be simple text files having each individual name on a single line like:

```
Michael
Christian
Peter
```